# Is the group $I_K/K^{\ast}$ compact?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, class-field-theory, adeles

I have two question on adeles and ideles:

$1)$Let $K$ be a number field. Is the group $I_K/K^{\ast}$ compact? 
Here $I_K$ is the idele group of $K$.

$2)$ Also it will be helpful if someone explains me in details the following :
The topologyof $I_K$ obtained as a subspace topology of $A_K \times A_K$ is the same as that of restricted product with $A_K^{\ast}$ with $O_v^{\ast}$. Here  $A_K$ is the adeles group of K

Answer (score 2):

There is a surjective absolute value morphism $I_K \to \mathbb R^{\times}_{>0}$ (given by taking the product of the absolute values on each factor), which (by the product formula) has $K^{\times}$ in its kernel.

Thus $I_K/K^{\times}$ surjects onto $R^{\times}_{> 0}$, and so is not compact.  On the other hand, the kernel of this surjection *is* compact. (This is equivalent to the finiteness of the class group together with Dirichlet's unit theorem.)

As for your second question, have you tried just writing it all out?